# SPARQL query items sharing distinct properties

Tags: sparql, wikidata

New to SPARQL, I'm trying to query Wikidata for all items that share at least k distinct values for a property with another item. For example, the following example is an attempt to list all diseases that share at least three different symptoms  (wdt:P780) with COVID-19 (wd:Q84263196) and list each disease and all its shared symptoms. The following query comes close:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?symptom1Label ?symptom2Label ?symptom3Label
WHERE 
{
 ?item wdt:P780 ?symptom1, ?symptom2, ?symptom3.
  wd:Q84263196 wdt:P780 ?symptom1, ?symptom2, ?symptom3.
  FILTER (?symptom1 != ?symptom2)
  FILTER (?symptom1 != ?symptom3)
  FILTER (?symptom2 != ?symptom3)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
} 
LIMIT 50
```

But the output shows all distinct combinations of three (common) symptoms. E.g.,

```
Q2840 influenza headache    cough   fatigue
Q2840 influenza headache    cough   nasal congestion
...
```

whereas the desired output should list each disease/symptom combination once (in either long or wide form).

Comment: adding a filter `filter(str(?symptom1) > str(?symptom2) && str(?symptom2) > str(?symptom3))` maybe helps to avoid the combinations of the symptoms

Comment: @UninformedUser not quite, it still is the case that c>b>a and d>b>a etc.

Comment: Another problem is that there could be more than 3 common symptoms.

Comment: I see, I forgot that there might be more than k overlapping symptoms - in that case I doubt that SPARQL is capable of solving this - indeed I might be wrong

Comment: Maybe like this: https://w.wiki/rpm

Comment: Also, diseases can have varying number of non-shared symptoms that can be used in differential diagnosis. So you need rather this: http://w.wiki/r$Z.
P.S. Do not self-diagnose :).

Comment: @StanislavKralin where in the links can I see the code? btw, if you post it as an answer, I can accept it and it would be more useful for others.

Comment: 1st query: https://w.wiki/rpm. 2nd query: https://w.wiki/sLV